# How to read data from a table in a checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a table(rs_insure) with a column named "id_cover" which has int values like 1(true), 0(false), and i want to list them in my view with a checkbox which has to be marked if is true and unmarked if is false, and obviously is readonly.

this is how i tried to do it

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($rs_insure as $insure)
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"> {{ $insure->id_employee}}   </td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $insure->charge }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $insure->desc}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{$insure->application_date}}</td>            
            <td class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" disabled="true" value=""/>
                {{ $insure->id_cover}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: What's the question here? How to associate that checkbox with the `$insure` object? How to send this to the server? What's going wrong in your code? Also, be aware that a `disabled` input isn't sent to the server when it's submitted.

Comment: @TimLewis im not gonna send anything, just list the values from the column in a checkbox

Comment: Ah, so simply setting the `checked` value based on the `$insure`? Might make more sense from a UI standpoint to not use a checkbox if you're not actually allowing interaction. A simple "YES" / "NO" string (or check/times icon) might be more appropriate? Otherwise the answers below both demonstrate different but valid approaches to setting default `checked` state based on `$insure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition to mark it as checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" value="" @if($insure->id_cover) checked @endif/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things,

1. If the `input` is disabled, it will not submit if it's part of a form, use the `readonly` property if that's your intention, otherwise it doesn't really matter.
2. Check to see if the object's property is true or not and with an in-line `if` simply add the checked property or nothing.

`<input type="checkbox" readonly {{ $insure->id_cover ? 'checked' : '' }} />`